# spring restTemplate dynamic mapping

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate

I am using spring restTemplate to map a response to a POJO. 
The response of the rest api is like this:

```
"attributes": {
    "name": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": ["John Doe"]
    },
    "permanentResidence": {
        "type": "Boolean",
        "value": [true]
    },
    "assignments": {
        "type": "Grid",
        "value": [{
            "id": "AIS002",
            "startDate": "12012016",
            "endDate": "23112016"
        },{
            "id": "AIS097",
            "startDate": "12042017",
            "endDate": "23092017"
        }]
    }
}
```

in the parent class, I have:

```
public class Users {
    private Map<String, Attribute> attributes;
}
```

If all the values of were String type, then I could have done like:

```
public class Attribute {
    private String type;
    private String[] value;
}
```

But the values are of different types. So I thought of doing the following:

```
public class Attribute {
    private String type;
    private Object[] value;
}
```

The above should work, but at every step I have to find out what is the type of Object.
So, my question is can I have something like this:

```
public class Attribute {

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    private String[] stringValues;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    private Boolean[] booleanValues;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    private Assignments[] assignmentValues; // for Grid type
}
```

But it is not working and throwing errors: `Conflicting setter definitions for property "value"`

**What is the recommended way of handling this scenario?**

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Jackson facilities for handling polymorphism here:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = BooleanAttribute.class, name = "Boolean"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = StringAttribute.class, name = "String")
})
class Attribute {
    private String type;
}

class BooleanAttribute extends Attribute {
    private Boolean[] value;
}

class StringAttribute extends Attribute {
    private String[] value;
}
```

[JsonTypeInfo](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html) tells Jackson that this is a base class and the type will be determined by a JSON field named `"type"`

[JsonSubTypes](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSubTypes.html) maps subtypes of `Attribute` to values of `"type"` in JSON.

If you add an appropriate subtype for `Assignments` and getters/setters Jackson will be able to parse your JSON.